# Baseline global seed data with FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot, fixtures

**TLDR**: What is the best approach to seed global data with FactoryBot?

Currently, we have a fairly large application and using FactoryBot for most tests.  However, we are still using fixtures to seed some default data in a database, for CRUD tests that need to talk to the DB, and ***can't be "stubbed"***.

Using fixtures to seed data, lets us shave off 50% of the time during setup/teardown for things that are common for almost all CRUD tests.

Also for some business rules validations, we need to use actual data, not 'faked' from Faker.

Examples of the seed model/fixtures:

- ShippingMethod  (FedEx, UPS, USPS, etc. )
- User (user record is used in almost every other model)
- Warehouse (we only have 2)
- Setting ( some global app settings)

**Actual Question**

What is the best practice to use inside FactoryBot to move away from using fixtures completely, so that we maintain test data in one spot, or this a good use-case for fixtures to be used with factories?

Keep in mind that since tests are run in parallel, seed data needs to be available to all tests throughout the run of the test suite.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: This question is a little unclear ... are you trying to use FactoryBot without the overhead of running actual "create" calls (which are slower than fixtures)?

Comment: @maxpleaner not really "without the overhead of running actual "create" calls " . But rather "is there a better / faster way?"